# Custom Post Type ACF date field wordpress

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

Good friends I have a custom post type with custom fields ACF of type date I have the following query:

```
$hoy= date('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'celebridades', // name custom post type
    'nopaging'      => true,
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'      => 'nacimiento_', //ACF date 
    'meta_query'    => array( array(
        'key' => 'nacimiento_', 
        'value' => $hoy, 
        'compare' => '>=', 
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ))
);
```

with the above query I get all the custom inputs,
I need to filter the entries according to the current day and month, the idea is to be able to visualize a list of celebrities who were born on a date like today.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try this code:

```
<?php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
 $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'celebridades', // name custom post type
        'posts_per_page'    => 4,
        'meta_key'          => 'nacimiento_', //ACF date  
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_value_num'    => $today,
        'meta_compare'      => '>'
    );
```